# Build Mozilla NSS tools for MAC OSX 10.10

Tags: macos, nss

When I check out the hg repo nss and nspr in a folder and run `make nss_build_all` in the nss folder, I got this error. Instruction as given [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/NSS_Sources_Building_Testing).

Did anybody successfully build nss tools in mac?

How can I resolve this issue?

```
pkix_pl_ldapdefaultclient.c:365:59: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'unsigned char *'
      from 'int' [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
 msg.protocolOp.op.bindResponseMsg.resultCode.data = OTHER;
                                                          ^ ~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[4]: *** [Darwin14.4.0_64_DBG.OBJ/pkix_pl_ldapdefaultclient.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [libs] Error 2
make[2]: *** [libs] Error 2
make[1]: *** [libs] Error 2
make: *** [libs] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: I downloaded a different version and that worked. I can't remember, but if I can find out I'll post the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spend a half day, however, solve the problem!

And I successfully managed to build the latest version of [NSS Tool 3.23](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/security/nss/releases/NSS_3_23_RTM/) on Mac OS - El Capitan
You can [download archive from my DropBox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15715229/Software/certutil_mac.zip)

Hope it would help to others